# Magento - New module edit action is creating a new item

Tags: image, magento, edit

I am creating a module to add banners. Now I have a problem when I want to edit a banner.

The problem is that when I click "save", Magento creates a new banner and doesn't modify the original banner. It happens when I modify something and if I don't modify anything and click "save".

I have another problem. I have an image fiel and it's working great but when I click "edit", it shows the preview image and the delete check box but the field is empty and if I save the banner it leaves the image field empty.

I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance, if you need more information ask me for it.

Comment: Adding the code in question to your question will help greatly.

Comment: I have attached some files (the grid, the form and the controller, they all are very short ^^) in this other post: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/263717/

Thanks for the comment (I always need to edit this, I hate that when I click "enter" it sends the comment jaja.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

about the saving of your banner, adapt the following code to your situation:
What is important here is to use the registry when saving.
Check too that the banner id is provided in $data when saving. Your form.php must provide it, add the code below before $form->setValues(...) line:

```
$model = Mage::registry('BannerManagement_data');
if ($model->getEntityId()) {
   $fieldset->addField('entity_id', 'hidden', array('name' => 'entity_id'));// or banner_id depends on what id title you gave in your database table
}
```

Of course you have to validate the input of the users beforeSave. Use the protected method _beforeSave() in your banner model to implement these input validation or in the controller directly in the save action.

```
/**
 * Common init to almost all actions
 */
protected function _initAction(){
    $this->_title ($this->__("Banner"));

    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_setActiveMenu('mymenu/banner');
    $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('banner')->__('Banners'), Mage::helper('banner')->__('Items'));
    }

    if(! Mage::registry('current_banner')){
        Mage::register('current_banner', Mage::getModel('banner/item'));
    }

    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    if (!is_null($id)) {
        $model = Mage::registry('current_banner')->load($id);

        if (! $model->getId()) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError(Mage::helper('banner')->__('This banner item no longer exists'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }
    }

    return $this;
}


/**
 * Banner edit page
 */ 
public function editAction(){
    $this->_initAction();
    $this->_title('Banner Edit');

    // 1. Get ID and create model
    $banner = Mage::registry('current_banner');

    // 2. set entered data if there had errors when we do save
    $data = $this->_getSession()->getBannerData(true);

    // 3. restore data from SESSION and provide a correct date format
    if (!empty($data)) {
        $banner->addData($data);
    }

    // 4. Build Edit form
    $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('banner')->__('Edit banner Item'), Mage::helper('banner')->__('Edit Banner Item'));
    $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('banner/adminhtml_banner'));
    $this->renderLayout();
}

/**
 * Subscritpion save process
 */ 
public function saveAction(){

    $this->_initAction();
    $banner = Mage::registry('current_banner');
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

    if ($data) {

        try {
            $banner->addData($data);
            $banner->save();

            $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(Mage::helper('banner')->__('The banner item has been saved.'));

            if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back', false)) {
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id'    => $banner->getId(), '_current'=>true));
                return;
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
            $this->_getSession()->setBannerData($banner->getData());
            $this->_redirectUrl($this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array('id' => $banner->getId())));
            return;
        }
    }
    $this->_redirectUrl($this->getUrl('*/adminhtml_overview'));
}
```

Comment: I have tried with the Mage::registry but is not working. And I don't know what is that ;)

How can I validate the data? I would like to be programming with php, without Magento...

Comment: check what I have written about your file form.php, the entity_id of your banner is missing as an hidden value

Comment: Yeah, I have added that but is not working either. I have seen that when I enter in the edit page I have all the correct data and the id.

Thanks a lot for the time that you are using with me.

Comment: Ok, now it's working. I have used a hidden field as you said and some changes in the controller and now is working. Thanks you very much.